# Qt: how to update model?

Tags: qt, viewmodel, qtableview

I'm trying to use Model-View approach in my app. I have a TableView that is filled by data. And I have several outside fields to edit data. As soon as I click the row I take the data from tableview's field and put into outside field. Then I want when I click the button the data into tableview to be updated from the field. How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QAbstractItemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) has a signal [`QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) that you need to emit when an Item is changed.

[`QAbstractItemView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) has a slot [`QAbstractItemView::update(const QModelIndex & index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#update) that you can call to update an item in a cell